# AJAX Login - Session Problem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I have created a working login script using AJAX and PHP, but my problem is - it makes me login twice before it can remember a session. Initially it uses js response to update the contents but if I refresh the page, everything turns back to its previous state. When I login for the second time and refresh the page, it's the only time it will work. Why is this happening?

You can check my files here:

1. login.php -
   http://pastebin.com/8UfyfuU1
2. users.php -
   http://pastebin.com/VBqMkpHH

Comment: I really didn't find any problems. Can you try to `alert('logout_Attempt');` in case $_POST['logout'] is true? won't it logout you imediatelly?

Comment: oaky sorry. and...do you ALWAYS receive        `alert('Login Success!');         `?

Comment: No, its about the contents  to know where I'm logged in or not. The alert part is an XHR response text.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you're not logged in while you connect to login.php but after you send the request you are. I suggest a js refresh after the http request sends back that you are logged in. See if that works, for exampe, if it returns 1, that means that the login data was correct and the page will refresh and you are logged in. If it returns 0, display a message that the login data was not correct. I don't know if it works but i assume.

Comment: No, I'm requesting to users.php from login.php using AJAX. I don't want the refresh to happen that's why I used AJAX. Just doing the manual refresh to confirm. I swear it's taking two logins. When doing AJAX post request I'm sure PHP session cookie is sent along with it too.